# Nesting same type JavaScript-objects with property fallbacking?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm looking for a method to create nested js-objects of the same type with property-fallbacking.

I'd like to be able to write for instance:

state.isLoggedIn and if this object doesn't have this property (undefined) then it should look in a base-state etc until no base-states exists anymore, then return undefined.

With base-state I mean some other state that this state is based on, not inherited like is class inheritance.

I was thinking of making some kind of class like this:

```
function State(base) {
    this.base = base; // also a state
}
```

When I try to get a property P from a state A that is based on another state B, and state A doesn't define a property P it should go look in state B instead.

I know I could use a function like state.getState(key) that looks in its own properties first and then in the base-properties. But I'm looking for a method of doing this with normal properties instead.

In C# it would look something like this (and making it a dynamic object I would get almost excatly the same ducked typed state I'm looking for in javascript):

```
class State
{
  public State(State base)
  {
    _base = base;
  }

  State _base;

  Dictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

  public object this[string key]
  {
    get { return _values.ContainsKey(key) ? _values[key] : _base[key]; }
    set { _values[key] = value; }
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Possible?

UPDATE:

This is what I got now:

```
function State() {
}

function ViewModelBase() {
    var self = this;
    self.__parent = ko.observable(null);
    self.state = new State();

    self.parent = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self.__parent();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            if (getObjectClass(value) !== "ViewModelBase") throw new Error("Wrong type of parent.");
            var p = self.__parent();
            if (p != null) throw new Error("Allready parented.");
            self.__parent(value);

            // here i'd like to inherit/nest self.state with value.state
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not inheritance? Prototypal inheritance seems like just what you're looking for.

Comment: I can't have different classes of states with predefined inheritance-chains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but maybe it is:

```
var state1 = {a : 1};
var state2 = Object.create(state1);
state2.b = 2;
console.log(state2.a); // 1
var state3 = Object.create(state2);
state3.a = 10; // creates an own "a" in state3
console.log(state1.a); // 1
console.log(state2.a); // 1
console.log(state3.b); // 2
```

This is using inheritance, as I suggested in my original comment to your question. `Object.create` returns a new object that uses the object passed as the first argument as its [[Prototype]] (which some implementations expose via the `__proto__` property). When you try to access a property of the new object and an own property is not found, it looks up in the prototype chain.

`Object.create` is not supported by older browsers, but a very simple polyfill is available [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for. The other method (__extends) seemed to copy the property values and so it was not possible to modify the parent-state and have if be reflected in the child-state. But with this method it works just fine. I can change state1.a and have state2.a return the same new value.

Answer (score 0):

This is what CoffeeScript uses for class extenstions (using prototype inheritance):

```
var __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
__extends = function (child, parent) {
    for (var key in parent) {
        if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key];
    }
    function ctor() {
        this.constructor = child;
    }
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new ctor();
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
    return child;
};
```

This assumes that the class functions are all a part of the prototype of the class functions.

---

For example:

```
Animal = (function() {

  function Animal() {}

  Animal.prototype.name = 'Generic Animal';

  Animal.prototype.my_sound = 'none';

  Animal.prototype.sound = function() {
    return console.log(this.my_sound);
  };

  return Animal;

})();

Cow = (function(_super) {

  __extends(Cow, _super);

  function Cow() {
    return Cow.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  Cow.prototype.name = 'Cow';

  Cow.prototype.my_sound = 'Moo';

  return Cow;

})(Animal);

Cat = (function(_super) {

  __extends(Cat, _super);

  function Cat() {
    return Cat.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  Cat.prototype.name = 'Cat';

  Cat.prototype.my_sound = 'Meow';

  return Cat;

})(Animal);
```

Comment: Hold your horses! =) I'm not looking for how to do protype inheritance. I'm looking for how to nest js-objects and use parent-properties as fallback for properties not found in the called object.

Comment: @AndreasZita Which is exactly one of the things that prototypal inheritance can accomplish.  :)

Comment: Hmmm maybee youre right. I don't know much about js. But I can't have classes of states with defined inheritance prior to creating the states and nesting them. I mean I will be creating states and connect/disconnect them in runtime... I have to look into this more =)

Comment: Tried this out in http://jsfiddle.net/nyHNS/ but with little luck. Not sure if I'm using it right. When the parent-state is modified the child-state still has the old values.

Comment: @AndreasZita `__extends` is **not** for objects... it is for prototypes